# hasClass selector callback in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.box').hasClass('done').removeClass('hide');
```

I want to remove hide from .box which has class done, but it doesn't work with above code. I'm very new to jquery.

Comment: You probably want `filter`.

Comment: Just to let you know why it failed. The `hasClass()` method returns a simple boolean value and is not chainable like many other other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Just append the class `.done`, so it will only target elements which have *both* `box` and `done` classes and then remove `hide` class from it using `removeClass`

```
$('.box.done').removeClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AmitJoki answer you append class `.done` with `.box` class

```
$('.box.done').removeClass('hide');
```

You can see **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u2x7f9ym/1/)** here.

Comment: Have you check `demo` which you want?